# RadGrid Set Column Navigation Property

Tags: asp.net, radgrid, navigation-properties

I'm having a problem with my RadGrid...Can you show me how can i on my aspx file set the column value of my grid with a navigation property field?

I'm using Entity, and I have the a table SapDocuments with a foreign Key of the field Process to another Table "Staging",

At this moment my grid comes with its value at null...

```
<MasterTableView GridLines="None" Width="100%" ViewStateMode="Disabled" CommandItemSettings-ShowExportToCsvButton="True"
                CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SequencialNumber" HeaderText="SequencialNumber"
                        UniqueName="SequencialNumber" SortExpression="SequencialNumber">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" UniqueName="Priority"
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter Priority column" SortExpression="Priority" DataType="System.Int32">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Process" HeaderText="Staging" UniqueName="Process"
                        SortExpression="Process" FilterControlAltText="Filter Process column">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SupplierCode" HeaderText="SupplierCode" UniqueName="SupplierCode"
                        SortExpression="SupplierCode" FilterControlAltText="Filter SupplierCode column">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MessageStatus" HeaderText="MessageStatus" UniqueName="MessageStatus"
                        SortExpression="MessageStatus" FilterControlAltText="Filter MessageStatus column">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="DocumentType" UniqueName="DocumentType"
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DocumentType column" SortExpression="DocumentType">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn UniqueName="InvoiceCreationDate" DataField="InvoiceCreationDate"
                        HeaderText="InvoiceCreationDate" FilterControlAltText="Filter InvoiceCreationDate column"
                        SortExpression="InvoiceCreationDate">
                        <FilterTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
                            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        </FilterTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SupplierVatNumber" FilterControlAltText="Filter SupplierVatNumber column"
                        HeaderText="SupplierVatNumber" SortExpression="SupplierVatNumber" UniqueName="SupplierVatNumber">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="False">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="19px"></HeaderStyle>
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="False">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                </RowIndicatorColumn>
            </MasterTableView>
            <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
            </FilterMenu>
            <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
            </HeaderContextMenu>
        </telerik:RadGrid
```

>

I need to set those two column values with the value of my navigation property....I can access to it like that:

- SapDocuments.Staging.Process;
- SapDocuments.Priorities.Priority;

  ```
  public List<SapDocuments> GetSapDocumentsByUser(string userName)
  {
      using (EscalonamentoFacturasEntities spDocs = new EscalonamentoFacturasEntities())
      {

          //Não é permitido projecções select new...
          var documentsQuery = from sd in spDocs.SapDocuments
                               join ua in spDocs.UsersAssign
                               on new { sd.Staging.Process, sd.Priorities.Priority }
                               equals
                               new { ua.Process, ua.Priority }
                               where ua.UserName == userName

                               //ALterar User

                               select sd;


          return documentsQuery.ToList();
  ```

My code behind is this:

```
 private void LoadData()
    {
        //Popular dados na Radlist

        SapDocumentsBO sapDocs = new SapDocumentsBO();
        this.SapDocuments = sapDocs.GetSapDocumentsByUser(Page.User.Identity.Name.Substring(Page.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\")+1));

        RadGrid1.DataSource = this.SapDocuments;


    }

    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable lazy loading on the object context?  If not, relationships will always be null, and you would have to manually instantiate them using the Load() method on the associated reference.  More on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846.aspx

EDIT: Also, you could consider

```
var documentsQuery = from sd in spDocs.SapDocuments
                             join ua in spDocs.UsersAssign
                             on new { sd.Staging.Process, sd.Priorities.Priority }
                             equals
                             new { ua.Process, ua.Priority }
                             where ua.UserName == userName
                             select new
                             {
                                 spDocs.SequentialNumber,
                                 Process = (spDocs.Staging != null) ? spDocs.Staging.Process : "",
                                 Priority = (spDocs.Priorities != null) ? spDocs.Priorites.Priority : ""
                             };
```

And return the result as IQueryable or IList.  That would make it really easy to bind.

Also, the RadGrid does support dot notation i believe like the following:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Priorities.Priority" HeaderText="Priority" ...
```

Comment: Thanks i had already put Lazy loading true...My DataGrid comes with data...but the problem is that when I create the relationships between table SapDocuments, Priorities(Field Priority) and Staging(Field Process), those fields became navigation properties on SapDocuments...and when the Grid loads, every column have values except the Priority and Process...I have to manualy instantiate them right?

Comment: If you are talking reading, and LazyLoadEnabled is true, then no, you don't have to manually instantiate them.  It's hard to tell what's going on, but I'm going to give you another option for binding above.

Comment: But at this moment something is missing on my code to bring data on columns Process and Priority, but i d'ont know what...

Comment: At this moment my entity SapDocuments d'ont have the fields Priority or Process...I only access them using navigation properties (Priorities and Staging)..Well as i have the column <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" UniqueName="Priority"
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter Priority column" SortExpression="Priority" DataType="System.Int32">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

Comment: I have to do some change on the aspx statement to tell my grid where the data for Priority and Process is?

Comment: On this.SapDocuments on fields Priority and Process i have um exception :   Message "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." string

Comment: OK, if you use the anonymous class approach I mentioned, you can use the DataField Priority directly.  If you are strongly typing SAPDocument, then you have to do have to set on the RadGrid column: DataField="Priorities.Priority"; you can't refer to the field directly.  Also, the exception you are getting is because you are disposing of the relationships directly with the using statement, so that definitely should be removed if you want lazy loading, or consider eager fetching via the .Include("Staging").Include("Priorities") on the object set in the LINQ query.

Comment: Thanks Brian, can you show me how the code staies using anonymous class and how can i stop disposing of the relationships directly??
Sorry i'm a newbie to the entity and aspx

Comment: using my statment and update my aspx <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Priorities.Priority" When I run i get the exception:"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." on the DataModel.designer on line: 
get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Priorities>("EscalonamentoFacturasModel.FK_SapDocuments_Priorities", "Priorities").Value;
            }
            set

Comment: Yes, remove the using statement, which disposes of the context after the code is done.  Or preload them using eager loading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: But i need to declare however the EscalonamentoFacturasEntities spDocs = new EscalonamentoFacturasEntities(); right? can you show me in code?? When I remove the using statement, I change the lines: Process = (sd.Staging != null) ? sd.Staging.Process : "", Priority = (sd.Priorities != null) ? sd.Priorites.Priority : "" but --> sd.Priorites.Priority is an int..Can you explain to me whath these two lines do? And what about my return documentsQuery.ToList();

Comment: Thanks for all Brian.. I remove the using statement and my code is:
var documentsQuery = from sd in spDocs.SapDocuments
                                     join ua in spDocs.UsersAssign
                                     on new { sd.Staging.Process, sd.Priorities.Priority }
                                     equals
                                     new { ua.Process, ua.Priority }
                                     where ua.UserName == userName
                                     select sd;

                return documentsQuery.ToList();